# rebar unable to get dependency from github

Tags: git, github, erlang, rebar

I am unable to get **any** dependency from github using rebar.

`rebar.config` file:

```
{sub_dirs, ["rel"]}.

{deps_dir, ["deps"]}.
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.

{deps, [
 {thrift_erl, "0.5.0", {git, "git://github.com/xslogic/thrift_erl", "HEAD"}}, 
 {eleveldb, "1.0.1", {git, "git://github.com/xslogic/eleveldb", "HEAD"}} 
]}.
```

When I do ./rebar compile I get:

```
Dependency not available: thrift_erl-0.5.0 ({git,
                                         "git://github.com/xslogic/thrift_erl",
                                         "HEAD"})
Dependency not available: eleveldb-1.0.1 ({git,
                                       "git://github.com/xslogic/eleveldb",
                                       "HEAD"})
```

It keeps looking for `DEP_NAME` with a **dash** at the end and can't seem to find it.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think that you should use `rebar get-deps` command firstly. 
If rebar compile command is error, try `rebar delete-deps`, `rebar clean`.
If still error, switch to the related deps directly, compile these project independently. (I have faced this problem one time).

Comment: Make sure you enter sudo rebar get-deps

Answer (score 1):

You forgot .get as stated before and with versions try to add commit number because they upgrade software and versions so master can point to different version and this breaks deps later.

So change `HEAD` to commit and set version to this commit or leave HEAD but set version to * (most current one)

This helps a lot later :)

Answer (score 0):

You git paths are simply incorrect.

You forget the the ".git" at the end. It should be `git://github.com/xslogic/eleveldb.git` not `git://github.com/xslogic/eleveldb`.

Comment: It worked after deleting the deps and getting them again. The paths are not complete but they do work with rebar.

Comment: To be precise; GitHub allows you to clone from either. Other Git providers may not be as forgiving.