# Trouble specifying rebar dependency when trying to profile couchdb using eflame

Tags: erlang, couchdb, rebar, rebar3

I am trying to use [eflame](https://github.com/proger/eflame) to profile CouchDB code to investigate some performance issues in my application. I tried adding the eflame dependency in `rebar.config.script` (https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/rebar.config.script)

However I get an error when I run `configure` to build CouchDB (2.0.0) from its source:

```
Dependency not available: eflame-.* ({git,
                                      "git://github.com/proger/eflame.git",
                                      {branch,"master"}})
ERROR: compile failed while processing /tmp/couchdb: rebar_abort
Makefile:67: recipe for target 'couch' failed
```

My change in the rebar.config.script in CouchDB source was adding a single line below (with a comma in the previous line of course)

```
{eflame, {url, "git://github.com/proger/eflame.git"}, {branch ,"master"}}
```

I tried various combinations of specifying the dependency  as shown in [rebar documentation](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/dependencies) but without any success.(I took into account the order of arguments in the `MakeDep` function in the rebar.config.script and accordingly tried to pass the arguments)

Any pointers to resolve will be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (Note : I am not familiar with Erlang or rebar , so please excuse any obvious mistakes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what's missing in your case is the second argument of the tuple, that requires the version number. You can use an asterix there if you don't need a specific one:

```
{eflame, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/proger/eflame.git", {branch, "master"}}}
```

Alternatively, if you are using [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/), you could use the [hex package](https://hex.pm/packages/eflame):

```
{eflame, "1.0.1"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry I should have made it clearer. The change which I made is in a file from which rebar.config is derived i.e. line 67 in https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/rebar.config.script   .So the ".*" is added in the function MakeDep

Comment: I see, ok. In that case I don't think this answer would be much help. I can remove this if you like.

Comment: no problem.Thank you ..It did help me better state the question. I edited the question now..

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues here

1)The version of rebar I was using was not > 1.5
2)I had to add get-deps before doing a rebar compile as given in this [rebar dependencies issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059579/rebar-unable-to-get-dependency-from-github) post