# rebar3 fails to fetch and copy dependencies (LFE project)

Tags: erlang, rebar3, lfe

After some years I'd like to back working with **Erlang/LFE**. I've a [little project](https://github.com/gsscoder/yfinance-lfe) I made to learn the language. I'm unable to fetch dependencies using `rebar3 get-deps` command.

It follows **rebar.config**, also available [here](https://github.com/gsscoder/yfinance-lfe/blob/master/rebar.config).

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info, {src_dirs, ["test"]}]}.
{lfe_first_files, []}.
{deps_dir, ["deps"]}.
{eunit_compile_opts, [
   {src_dirs, ["test"]}
  ]}.
{deps, [
   {lfe, "0.9.0", {git, "git://github.com/rvirding/lfe.git", {tag, "v0.9.0"}}},
   {clj, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/lfex/clj.git"}},
   {lhc, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/lfex/lhc.git"}},
   {ljson, ".*", {git, "git@github.com:lfex/ljson.git", "master"}}, 
   {ltest, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/lfex/ltest.git", {tag, "0.4.1"}}}
  ]}.
```

I know that I've referenced an old version of **LFE**... But if I remove all deps and try to add them again: the first that fails is `clj`. However with `rebar.config` in its original state, I got the following output after `rebar3 get-deps`. Complete output [here](https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/44259dbc649c0c6f3fc3e7635b9a0b9c).

```
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Fetching clj (from {git,"git://github.com/lfex/clj.git"})
===> WARNING: It is recommended to use {branch, Name}, {tag, Tag} or {ref, Ref}, otherwise updating the dep may not work as expected.
===> Fetching lfe-compile (from {git,"https://github.com/lfe-rebar3/compile.git",
                       {tag,"0.5.0"}})
===> Fetching lfe (from {git,"https://github.com/rvirding/lfe.git",
               {ref,"697e9b4996fa843f4c6a9edea25005d30a9b8a14"}})
===> Compiling lfe
...
===> Compiling ltest
 ~~>    Finding .lfe files ...
 ~~>    Compiling ./_build/default/plugins/ltest/src/ltest.lfe ...
 ~~>    Compiling ./_build/default/plugins/ltest/src/ltest-const.lfe ...
 ~~>    Compiling ./_build/default/plugins/ltest/src/ltest-formatter.lfe ...
 ~~>    Compiling ./_build/default/plugins/ltest/src/ltest-unit.lfe ...
 ~~>    Compiling ./_build/default/plugins/ltest/src/ltest-runner.lfe ...
===> Plugin {'lfe-test',{git,"https://github.com/lfe-rebar3/test.git",
                                    {tag,"0.4.0-rc2"}}} not available. It will not be used.
===> Fetching lfe-clean (from {git,"https://github.com/lfe-rebar3/clean.git",
                     {tag,"0.4.0-rc2"}})
===> Compiling lfe-clean
 ~~>    Finding .lfe files ...
 ~~>    Compiling ./_build/default/plugins/lfe-clean/src/lr3-cln-util.lfe ...
===> Plugin {'lfe-clean',{git,"https://github.com/lfe-rebar3/clean.git",
                                     {tag,"0.4.0-rc2"}}} not available. It will not be used.
===> Fetching ljson (from {git,"git@github.com:lfex/ljson.git","master"})
===> WARNING: It is recommended to use {branch, Name}, {tag, Tag} or {ref, Ref}, otherwise updating the dep may not work as expected.
===> Failed to fetch and copy dep: {git,"git@github.com:lfex/ljson.git","master"}
```

I checked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059579/rebar-unable-to-get-dependency-from-github) and [documentation](http://blog.lfe.io/tutorials/2016/03/25/0858-lfe-and-rebar3/), but I was still unable to fix the problem.

My system is **macOS** Catalina. It follows **Erlang** environment versions:
**ERLANG** 22.2.1, **LFE** 1.3, **REBAR3** 3.12.0.

All installed with `brew`. Please let me know if more details are needed.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I am positive this is the issue induced by that you use untagged `master` git sources everywhere. I would start with setting all the versions to last values explicitly, one by one. `rebar` is not a magician, help it.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks for suggestion but It's something I've already tried... Anyway I tried again and didn't work. I've removed `master` and other `tag`s. But `rebar3` stil complains about `ljson`: `Failed to fetch and copy...`. Tried also `rebar3 clean`. There's other I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally discovered that referencing `lfe/clj` and `lfe/lhc` is redudant, since these packages are indirectly and correctly referenced in implicit way from other ones.

I've removed these from **rebar.config**, updated to latest syntax and used `tag` when possible (otherwise `master`). I switched **all URLs** to use `https://` instead of SSH with scheme `git://`.

Now I'm able to get dependencies with `rebar3 get-deps` and compile with `rebar3 compile`.

Updated **rebar.config**:

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info, {src_dirs, ["test"]}]}.
{lfe_first_files, []}.
{deps_dir, ["deps"]}.
{eunit_compile_opts, [
   {src_dirs, ["test"]}
  ]}.
{deps, [
   {lfe, {git, "https://github.com/rvirding/lfe.git", {"tag", "v1.3"}}},
   {ljson, {git, "https://github.com/lfex/ljson.git", "master"}},
   {ltest, {git, "https://github.com/lfex/ltest.git", {tag, "0.9.0"}}}
  ]}.
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Changing protocol from git to https in URL did the trick for me